# Images in SVG Image tags not showing up in Chrome, but displays locally?

Tags: html, css, svg, web

For some reason, Chrome is displaying the SVG without the images in its Image tags.

Here is a sample from my SVG:

```
<image xlink:href="blocker.png" height="312.666661" width="85.693825" y="16.479997" x="459.946664"/>
```

blocker.png is a local file, but I also tried uploading it to imgur, but that didn't work either.

Here is the svg tag:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Here is what it looks like locally:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga7je.png

Here is what it looks like on a live webpage:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNmt.png

As you can see, the two players are missing. This doesn't happen when I upload the SVG online, but when I try to link that URL to my page, the same thing happens

Not sure if it's relevant, but here is the HTML code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG</title> 
<style>
img{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 800px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <img src="svg.svg"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you make sure to change the path of the `<image>` tag to reflect the changes? I.e. change `blocker.png` to `http://imgur.com/you/ABCDEF` or whatever else the link is

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, I made sure I did. I loaded it up locally, it showed up. Loaded on my webpage, it did not.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

PaulLeBeau's answer is right. But another solution is to use an `embed` tag instead of an `img` tag for the picture.

```
<embed src="svg.svg">
```

[Here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML) are some ways to embed svg images in HTML.

Comment: Wow! What a sleek answer! How did you find out this `embed` tag?

Comment: Warning: This solution caused my page to load forever. My cpu on local machine clocked  to %100!

Answer (score 28):

Another solution that worked for me is, open SVG image in any editor (Vs code or Notepad++) and replace

```
xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,
```

to

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
```

img to image.

Hope this helps if someone is still looking for it.

Comment: This worked well for me. Thank you. To speed it up if you have a lot of svg files: `sed -i '' -e 's/data:img/data:image/g' *.svg`

Comment: it looks like your examples are incomplete, you have left an open quote tag in your xlink:href, could you elaborate how this would look with a local image? I'm attempting with xlink:href="data:image/jpg;base64,/path/to/jpeg.jpg" and doesn't seem to function how I'd expect it to.

Comment: @Gloat the example was provided to replace `img` with `image` text only, rest will be the same.

Answer (score 21):

When you load an SVG into a webpage using an `<img>` element, the SVG has to be self-contained.  It cannot link to third part resources like you are doing by linking to the PNG files.  This a privacy restriction imposed by the browser.

Possible solutions are:

1. Convert your PNG to Data URI format and include them in your SVG that way.
2. Convert your blocker PNG(s) to actual SVG elements, such as a `<path>`.

Comment: If that were true, it wouldn't work either when I upload it to online image hosting websites, which it did.

Comment: Viewing the SVG in your browser (ie. the `.svg` file) is fine, because you are not loading it via an `<img>`. The same applies if your image hosting site hosts and serves the `.svg` file directly rather than embedding it via an `<img>`.

Comment: Why this is needed?

Answer (score 2):

I happened to find out that Chrome [v 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)] doesn't show the image inside svg if the image file is not located at html root directory.
The .svg and the embedded .png files were placed in /images -folder, the .svg content came up right in Chrome, but not the embedded .png. When the .png was copied to (../)  the html root, Chrome works.

However, Firefox [v 52.0.2 (32-bit)] seems to work fine when .svg and .png are in the same /images folder.

Edit: Actually in my case I load the svg with d3.xml(..) method for getting js handle to the actual svg elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the .htaccess file in the root:

`AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz`

This is what I had in the Headers >> Network >> Content-Type. Should be 'image/svg+xml' not 'txt/plain....'

By adding the above code, my SVGs rendered within img tags.

[image: In the netword tab in dev tools, check that the Headers >> Content-Type is 'image/svg+xml'. The below shows my incorrect setup that did not display svg in img tags]

Answer (score -2):

we should add the one namespace identifier in the src tag in img.src file

xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" add this to the src tag as attribute in the img.svg file.