# SVG—included image does not show up

Tags: php, svg, http-headers

I have a php script that generates SVG graphics on the fly. The script takes a get parameter, which is a path to a image file - works like that:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/generic.php?src=<rawurlencoded path to existing img>

Content-Type: Content-type: image/svg+xml

<!-- 
     namespace attributes for svg and xlink are there 
     as well as viewBox and so on
-->
<svg>
  <!-- shortened -->
  <!-- x,y,width,height are set -->
  <image xlink:href="</path/to/existing/img.png>" />
</svg>
```

If I drop the url (/generic.php) into the address bar of the browser, the image pops up as expected. **BUT** if I include that in the HTML:

```
<img src="/generic.php?src=<rawurlencoded path to existing img>" />
```

All the svg stuff shows up, but not the image. Is [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rawurlencode.php) the right method for the `<img>` tag? Do I need some others headers here?

The website currently runs within a docker container which is started like so:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 .
```

So the incoming port is 80.

The HTML output is created like that:

```
{%
  set url = config.theme.artwork.route ~ '?'
    ~  'src='      ~ (img == null ? '' : img.url)|url_encode
%}
<div>
  <img src="{{ url }}" />
</div>
```

I have just tested that:

```
<iframe width="100px" height="100px" src="{{ url }}"></iframe>
```

Works…

Comment: Whats the php reaction code inside `generic.php`? How does it utilize `src`, and output/stream it? It might be a missing `header()` setting. `rawurlencode` is ok, generally I just use `urlencode`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat `header()` is called before `echo` and `exit`. As I said, it works if I drop the url directly in the browser, but not it the url included in an `<img>`

Comment: Well, you have me baffled. If your generic.php is displaying the svg correctly by directly hitting it in a browser... then it should be working ok as the `src` of an `img` tag :(

Comment: The `xlink:href="/…"` starts with a slash, so it is absolute. I have also tried to prepend the whole `http://localhost:8080` stuff, but that didn't change a thing…

Comment: Was only a thought. I'm myffed, and annoyed at my inability to spot the issue, given how... this should be working like you thought.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I think so too ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195767/2960971 ... after some tests with just a plain test.svg file and the img tag (vs just included the file as html)... I can confirm, img tags dont like svg with inner images. I did find that simply doing this worked ok (YMMV): `echo file_get_contents('/generic.php?src=/test.png');`

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks for that! Even if I haven't heard of those `<embed>` tags they work for that, two.

Comment: `embed` are pretty old school. They need a lot of formatting and adjustments to prevent scrollbars and ugliness. But yeah, those work too.