# svg file doesn't open even though its path is correct on html page of spring boot project

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, svg, thymeleaf

I was gonna use Metronic html login page in my spring boot thymeleaf project, so I updated code to import assets.

```
  <link th:href="@{/uploads/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link th:href="@{/uploads/assets/css/style.bundle.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

css files are loaded and applied on the page, but svg file doesn't open. I can only see alt "Logo" as text.

```
<!-- doesn't work -->
<a href="/index.html" class="mb-7">
   <img alt="Logo" th:src="@{/uploads/assets/media/logos/logo.svg}" />
</a>
```

If I put png file in the same path, then it works

```
<a href="/index.html" class="mb-7">
   <img alt="Logo" th:src="@{/uploads/assets/media/logos/logo.png}" />
</a>
```

Please help me to get this reason

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your SVG file isn't valid.

Comment: I've checked it already and it is working on metronic html page

Comment: What do you see in dev tools? Any 404 error logs? Your server may be missing correct mime type definitions for svgs. However please post a svg example. If an icon svg contains external image references it may also cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, please tell me about the mime type for svgs

Comment: What @herrstrietzel said. In browser developer tools, look at the individual request for the svg URL, and see what MIME type is returned in the response header. Both for your failing case and the successful example. I suspect that Spring is not configured to serve the correct MIME type for svg.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a case with thymeleaf or spring-boot (since no details on spring-boot configuration etc.) but it might be related to SVG loading.

Please refer to this SO post for details [Images in SVG Image tags not showing up in Chrome, but displays locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195669/images-in-svg-image-tags-not-showing-up-in-chrome-but-displays-locally)

You can simply use an `embed` tag.

Comment: It showed 200 OK